# Is there any way to specify the auto-generated key that firebase makes when you push an object to the rtdb?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push something to the firebase rtdb and I would like to access it elsewhere pretty easily. This is what I am using to add to the rtdb:

```
function addStudentHandler(studentData) {
        fetch(
            "url that I put in real code",
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(studentData),
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                }
            }
        )
        .then (() => {
            history.replace("/");
        });
    }
```

Is there like a title value or some other kind of value to specify it instead of having auto-generated unique keys? I appreciate any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your own code that tells Firebase to generate a unique key, because you are using the `POST` method. As specified in the documentation on [saving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data):

> `POST`: Add to a list of data in our Firebase database. Every time we send a POST request, the Firebase client generates a unique key, like `fireblog/users/<unique-id>/<data>`

If you want to specify the complete path yourself, you can use `PUT` which is documented as:

> `PUT` Write or replace data to a defined path, like `fireblog/users/user1/<data>`.

So when you specify `PUT`, you specify the entire path to write to, Firebase won't generate a unique ID under the path, and will simply write the value you specify to the path you specify.

---

In your existing code:

```
fetch(
    "url that I put in real code/user1.json", // 
    {
        method: "PUT",                        // 
        body: JSON.stringify(studentData),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    }
)
```